How to create a stacked bar chart with a totals column and labels of percentages for all the bars with ggplot2?
I am trying to produce a stacked bar chart with a column of totals and labels of percentages in each bar. But somehow I only manage to do either one or the other. Any help towards getting both things simultaneously would be very appreciated.
here goes an excerpt of my farm_size1 database:
structure(list(SPTOT = c(2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CASE = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), case1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), case2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("Bierge", "Santa Creu", "Collbató", "Monells"
), class = "factor"), sptot1 = structure(c(2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), sptot2 = c("50-100 Ha", 
"> 500 Ha", "> 500 Ha", "> 500 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "201-500 Ha", 
"201-500 Ha", "101-200 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "50-100 Ha", 
"101-200 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "> 500 Ha", "50-100 Ha", 
"101-200 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "201-500 Ha")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

And this is the code I used to produce the proportional stacked bart chart with a column for totals:
farm_size1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=case2)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=sptot2), position="fill")+
  geom_bar(aes(x="Total", fill=sptot2), position= "fill")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FB8072","#FBB4AE","#FDB462", "#2a7dad","#8DD3C7","#E6F5C9"),
                    labels=c("< 50 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "101-200 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "> 500 Ha"))+
  labs(x= "", y="Percentage", fill= "Farm size")

And this looks like this:

And the code for producing the percentage labels is this:
farm_size1 %>%
  count(case2, sptot2)%>%
  group_by(case2)%>%
  mutate(pct=prop.table(n)*100)%>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(case2, pct, fill=sptot2)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ylab("Percentage of farms") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct),"%")),
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FB8072","#FBB4AE","#FDB462", "#2a7dad","#8DD3C7","#E6F5C9"),
                    labels=c("< 50 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "101-200 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "> 500 Ha"))

And I produced the following graph:


You can add new data to your data frame making so that every case2 is equal "Total"
farm_size1 %>%
  #new code
  bind_rows(farm_size1 %>% mutate(case2 = "Total")) %>% 
  #########
  count(case2, sptot2)%>%
  group_by(case2)%>%
  mutate(pct=prop.table(n)*100)%>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(case2, pct, fill=sptot2)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ylab("Percentage of farms") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct),"%")),
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FB8072","#FBB4AE","#FDB462", "#2a7dad","#8DD3C7","#E6F5C9"),
                    labels=c("< 50 Ha", "50-100 Ha", "101-200 Ha", "201-500 Ha", "> 500 Ha"))



many thanks! I was trying to use the same code for another part of database where I have a variable with different categories (like sptot2 above) but with counts of observations for each category, but it does not work. Any suggestion on how to deal with it would be must welcomed. May thanks in advance!
